# How do I edit Endless adapter in a way that the loading stops if there is no data to load?

Tags: android, listview, commonsware-cwac

The endless adapter that I've used in my code, doesn't stop expecting data even if I am out of it. Thus the throbbing symbol, which is the loading symbol here, keeps on circling expecting some data.

How do I stop it? How do I make the endless adapter know that I'm out of data?

Also, I would like to tweak the adapter so that it can use multiple lists. Is it possible? By multiple lists, I mean list embedded inside another list. If yes, is there an example or any ideas as to how to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How do I make the endless adapter know that I'm out of data?

Quoting [the documentation](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless):

> Your `EndlessAdapter` subclass also needs to implement `cacheInBackground()`. This method will be called from a background thread, and it needs to download more data that will eventually be added to the `ListAdapter` you used in the constructor. While the demo application simply sleeps for 10 seconds, a real application might make a Web service call or otherwise load in more data.
>
> This method returns a `boolean`, which needs to be `true` if there is more data yet to be fetched, `false` otherwise.
>
> Since this method is called on a background thread, you do not need to fork your own thread. However, at the same time, do not try to update the UI directly.
>
> If you expected to be able to retrieve data, but failed (e.g., network error), that is fine. However, you should then return `false`, indicating that you have no more data.

---

> Also, I would like to tweak the adapter so that it can use multiple lists. Is it possible? By multiple lists, I mean list embedded inside another list.

No. Android does not support the notion of lists inside of lists. You are welcome to take a look at my [`MergeAdapter`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge) (if you really mean that you wish to concatenate multiple lists together) or Android's `ExpandableListView` (if your lists-in-lists is really some sort of shallow tree structure).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use different data for your own Adapter this data can be of any type such as 
`ArrayList<HashMap/HashSet<?,List<?>>>` it is your own business how you will use it within your getView(...) method. You can implement a poller service which will update your Adapter with data accordingly and setAdapter() after. If there's no data just idle...
hope this helps abit.